# Java SSL exception: Unable to create StAX reader or writer

Tags: java, ssl

I have a C# application that send a SOAP request to a Java web service, and it works fine. However, when I activate SSL, in some communication I get below exception:

> com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.MessageCreationException: Couldn't create
> SOAP message due to exception: Unable to create StAX reader or writer.

I am sure that SSL is implemented correctly, but some messages fail with this error.

Comment: The exception itself doesn't seem to have anything to do with SSL. It reports that it can't create a StAX (Streaming API for XML) reader or writer. Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: This is **not** an SSL exception. It is a SOAP exception. Be accurate. Be precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours, I found a solution myself.

It is a timeout problem, if timeout a is set with a small value for SOAP connection in my C# service side , this error can occur.